# Lock EF 6 insert when calling same url multiple times at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC 6 application. When a user enters the client-side in Angular, I do some calls to the ASP.NET's Async API's.In some places, I call the Api 3-4 times to get other resources.

I'm also keeping a User table in my database, connected with EF 6. Here I create a new User row when the user that enters (using Windows Auth) doesn't already exist and add the 'Public'-role to him.

However, when the user enters the page that calls the Api 3-4 times first, the user gets created 3-4 times because the 'Create' is not locking the table, thus creating the user 3 times.

How can I lock the table (repository in my case) to have the next calls wait for the lock to be removed and then do the 'GetAsync' to check if the user exists?

The code that is being called 3 times:

```
        var currentUserName = User.Identity.Name;
        var currentUser = await _userRepository.GetAsync(u => u.UserName == currentUserName);

        // Create user that does not yet exist
        if (currentUser != null) return HttpBadRequest();

        var user = new User(currentUserName);

        using(new CreatedBySystemProvider(_userRepository))
        {
            _userRepository.Add(user);
            await _userRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
            await user.AddRoleAsync(AppSumRoles.Authenticated);
            /* Temporary add SysAdmin role */
            if(string.Equals(currentUserName, @"BIJTJES\NilsG", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                using(new CreatedBySystemProvider(_userRoleRepository))
                {
                    await user.AddRoleAsync(AppSumRoles.SysAdmin);
                }
            }
            currentUser = await _userRepository.GetAsync(u => u.Id == user.Id);
        }

        return Ok(currentUser);
```

Comment: Use something on the request as a unique identifier for the user. Something like their IP or something

Comment: If the username should be unique, you can create a unique index on username and handle the exception in case that multiple parallel requests try to create the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving the `CreateUser` code into a separate API. User creation should be a separate use case, not an implicit part of every other use cases. Don't mix concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider refactory your user creating process. But simply for your question you can do something like this

(For details pls see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx)

```
private static readonly AsyncLock asyncLocker = new AsyncLock(); 

var currentUserName = User.Identity.Name;

using(var releaser = await asyncLocker.LockAsync()) 
{
    var currentUser = await _userRepository.GetAsync(u => u.UserName == currentUserName);

    // Create user that does not yet exist
    if (currentUser != null) return HttpBadRequest();

    var user = new User(currentUserName);

    using(new CreatedBySystemProvider(_userRepository))
    {
        _userRepository.Add(user);
        await _userRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
        await user.AddRoleAsync(AppSumRoles.Authenticated);
        /* Temporary add SysAdmin role */
        if(string.Equals(currentUserName, @"BIJTJES\NilsG", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            using(new CreatedBySystemProvider(_userRoleRepository))
            {
                await user.AddRoleAsync(AppSumRoles.SysAdmin);
            }
        }
        currentUser = await _userRepository.GetAsync(u => u.Id == user.Id);
    }
}

return Ok(currentUser);
```